# Nginx issue serving CSS files.

Tags: css, nginx

I am trying to serve all my static assets via nginx.  The javascript I have is loading in fine however the css keeps coming in with Content-Type:text/plain.  This is causing the browser to not use the css file.  Here is my nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       80;

        location / {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /opt/app/public;
        }
    }
}
```

The include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Most of the stack overflow threads recommend including the mime types which I already have and it did not fix my issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    root /www/data;

    location / {
    }

    location /images/ {
    }

    location ~ \.(mp3|mp4) {
        root /www/media;
    }
}
```